# using a SqlConnection in C++ / .NET

Tags: .net, c++, sql-server, msdn, using-statement

When I go to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Y4810) page for the `SqlConnection` class, it only shows examples in C# and VB.  Why doesn't MSDN show a C++ example?

I am particularly interested in how a C++ example would get around the lack of the `using` keyword in C++.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to use the `System.Data.dll` in your C++ project?

Comment: Answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205802/best-portable-way-to-connect-to-sql-server-using-c

Comment: also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338950/what-is-the-managed-c-equivalent-to-the-c-sharp-using-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... after reading [What is the Managed C++ equivalent to the C# using statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338950/what-is-the-managed-c-equivalent-to-the-c-sharp-using-statement) it seems that the equivalent of:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // SqlCommand and so...
}
```

is actually:

```
{
  SqlConnection conn(connectionString);

  // SqlCommand and so...
}
```

That is quite impressive, since C++ does not "lack" the`using` statement as much as it **removes the need for it entirely**!  I don't think that C#/VB programmers sufficiently appreciate that advantage of C++ (I certainly didn't :) .