# cannot convert argument 1 from 'System::IO::StreamWriter ^' to 'System::IO::Stream ^ in windows form

Tags: c++-cli

here is my code i can't seem to write data on my  file.

```
StreamWriter sw = gcnew StreamWriter(Application::StartupPath + "\\Employee\\" +""+NameE->Text + "" +NumberE->Text + "" +EmailE->Text + ".txt" , true);//Path to write .txt file

    sw.WriteLine(label1->Text + " " + NameE->Text);
    sw.WriteLine(label2->Text + " " + NumberE->Text);
    sw.WriteLine(label3->Text + " " + EmailE->Text);
    sw.Close();
```

I keep Getting this error

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2664
>   'System::IO::StreamWriter::StreamWriter(const System::IO::StreamWriter %)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'System::IO::StreamWriter ^' to 'System::IO::Stream ^'t

Comment: By reading the compiler errors, you can see that the compiler is not able to parse the 1st argument supplied to StreamWriter. You can try to split the concatenation and try to print the strings one after another to debug the issue.

Comment: You're also missing the `^` on `sw`, since you're using `gcnew`

Comment: The compiler is struggling to find a constructor overload for this invalid code.  Google "c++/cli stack semantics" to find the correct way to do this, very important to learn how to get ahead in C++/CLI.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11087648/17034

Answer (score 1):

```
StreamWriter sw = gcnew StreamWriter(...);
```

`gcnew` returns a managed reference. This is analogous to C++, where `new` returns a pointer. In C++, you specify a pointer by using a `*`: `MyType* foo = new MyType(...)`. In C++/CLI, you specify a managed reference by using a `^`.

```
StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(...);
//          ^-- Right here.
```