# Finding working destructor for gcroot<Bitmap^> class in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, bitmap, c++-cli, destructor

Sorry for my english. I want to free memory that was used by gcroot objejct. Here is a simple example that returns me an error. On **MSDN** I found that there is a [Dispose()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8th8381z.aspx) method for Bitmap object. When I'm trying to use this method for gcroot object MS VC 2010 returns me this message. How can I free this memory?

> picture_box_main_handler.cpp(194): error C2039: Dispose: is not a member of "gcroot"

```
gcroot<Bitmap^>  new_image = gcnew Bitmap(500,500);
new_image.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't trying to call the method on the 'gcroot' itself (so you don't want the . syntax).

However, `Dispose` for `IDisposable` is special in C++/cli.   You use the `delete` keyword for that:

So you can just call:

```
delete new_image;
```

and that will call Dispose on the underlying `Bitmap ^`.

You may want to use `auto_handle` to take care of disposal automatically.  See this question:

[C++/CLI Resource Management Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218925/c-cli-resource-management-confusion/9219844#9219844)